# CSS actv button not

Tags: css

I took one example code from a site...Slide Image...but the :active button 'background-color: black' change is not working !!

**Here is the link:**

http://colegioramoslopez.com/Carlos_Web/Estudos/CSS/Imagens/Exemplo_7.html

Here is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .slider-holder {
      width: 800px;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: yellow;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .image-holder {
      width: 2400px;
      background-color: red;
      height: 400px;
      clear: both;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-transition: left 2s;
      -moz-transition: left 2s;
      -o-transition: left 2s;
      transition: left 2s;
    }
    
    .slider-image {
      float: left;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #slider-image-1:target~.image-holder {
      left: 0px;
    }
    
    #slider-image-2:target~.image-holder {
      left: -800px;
    }
    
    #slider-image-3:target~.image-holder {
      left: -1600px;
    }
    
    .slider-change {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 20px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: #ddd;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    .slider-change:hover {
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .slider-change:active,
    .slider-change:focus {
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="slider-holder">
    <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
    <div class="image-holder">
      <img src="1.jpg" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="2.jpg" class="slider-image" />
      <img src="3.jpg" class="slider-image" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center>
    <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
    <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
    <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello everbody !!

I took one example code from a site...Slide Image...but the :active button 'background-color: black' change is not working !!

**Here is the link:**

http://colegioramoslopez.com/Carlos_Web/Estudos/CSS/Imagens/Exemplo_7.html

Comment: Is this link a broken one or the example that you took from the "site"?

Comment: It´s not the original link......but the code is the same..!!

Comment: It will be awesome to reproduce code which cause the problem on jsfiddle, codepen or on anythink like them. Because I could  not figure out what is the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this the right way but you can do it as below:

Add `id` in your HTML

```
<a href="#slider-image-2" id="slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-1" id="slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
<a href="#slider-image-3" id="slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
```

And in your CSS add this:

```
  #slider-image-1:target, #slider-image-2:target, #slider-image-3:target{
  background: black;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think that happens because you have `span` with the same `id`